# Any suggestions for a simple jquery slider with auto height and custom prev/next navigation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I'm having a bit of trouble finding a nice little jquery plugin that would allow me to slide through testimonials on my website.

The testimonials could be different lengths, so ideally I would like the slider to be able to auto adjust depending on the length of the testimonial.

I would also really like to be able to create custom prev/next links, so that I can place them where ever I want and style them how I like.

I've found these couple so far:

http://slidesjs.com/ (auto-height: yes | custom prev/next links: no)

http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/ (auto-height: yes | custom prev/next: yes)

The second option looks like it may suit what I want, as it has both the auto-heigh ability and the custom prev/next links ability.

If anyone has any other suggestions though, I would be very grateful to hear them.

There seems to be loads of jquery sliders out there, but I can find very few with these requirements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :o)

Comment: I like the SudoSlider, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: No problem, I've only just found it too, looks quite nice hey.

Comment: +1 for linking to SudoSlider.  I like the auto-height demos.

Comment: Me too, as there doesn't seem to be very many sliders around with auto-height options.

Comment: There are several "TAB" plugins which have animated autoheight. Just hide the navigationpart and use setInterval to animate throgh.

Comment: Wow... SudoSlider is AWESOME! Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is my favorite:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/

you can put the testimonials all in a list and them after loading the js do:

```
$(".slideshow").cycle();
```

It will let each testimonial have it's own height and i believe it does next/prev too.

Comment: I've used the cycle plugin a few times before and it's great! Not sure it has the auto height feature I am looking for though. I had a look and found that you can perhaps make the cycle plugin act how I would like, but you have to add an onAfter function. More details can be found here: [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-auto-height)

Comment: here is a site that uses it, with testimonials of differing length: http://www.logonscience.com/html/about.php

Comment: It does seem to work. Not sure if in that example they were to have a div below their testimonials, this div would move up and down nicely depending on the height of the testimonial. Maybe it would, I'd have to look into it. The main thing I was after was a nice animated auto height effect. I'm using [slidesjs](http://slidesjs.com/) atm, as I worked out how to add custom prev/next navigation and it has a nice sliding auto height effect :)

Comment: @ade123 I'm curious... How did you add custom prev/next nav to Slidesjs? did you simulate clicks on hidden prev/next links using `trigger`?

Comment: Sorry Julien, It's been a while since I did it now, so can't remember exactly what I did. Here's the page that I used it on though http://www.elementgraphics.co.uk/development/adrian/